# UDP packet sent to a multicast destination is sent via the loopback interface

Tags: windows, sockets, windows-10, winsock, multicast

I'm running *Windows 10*.
I had recently diagnosed an issue with my computer where any packet sent to a multicast destination is sent through the loopback interface rather than the 'default' one (see my adventures [here](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/17477)).

Example code:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.sendto(b"herpyderp", ('224.0.0.251', 5353))
```

The packet is seen on the loopback interface only (used *Microsoft Message Analyzer* to sniff).

I tried inspecting the routing table via `route print`, and got the following output:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      10.0.10.138       10.0.10.30     35
        10.0.10.0    255.255.255.0         On-link        10.0.10.30    291
       10.0.10.30  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.0.10.30    291
      10.0.10.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.0.10.30    291
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.0.10.30    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.0.10.30    291
===========================================================================
```

You'll note the metric indicates the packet should be sent through my 'default' interface.

I then tried inspecting the interface metric via the *PowerShell* `Get-NetIPInterface` cmdlet (as implied [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2015/08/14/adjusting-the-network-protocol-bindings-in-windows-10/)), and got the following output:

```
ifIndex InterfaceAlias                  AddressFamily NlMtu(Bytes) InterfaceMetric Dhcp     ConnectionState PolicyStore
------- --------------                  ------------- ------------ --------------- ----     --------------- -----------
2       Ethernet 3                      IPv6                  1500              35 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
7       Ethernet                        IPv6                  1500               5 Enabled  Disconnected    ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv6            4294967295              75 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
3       isatap.home                     IPv6                  1280              75 Disabled Disconnected    ActiveStore
17      Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Inte... IPv6                  1280              75 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
2       Ethernet 3                      IPv4                  1500              35 Enabled  Connected       ActiveStore
7       Ethernet                        IPv4                  1500               5 Enabled  Disconnected    ActiveStore
1       Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1     IPv4            4294967295              75 Disabled Connected       ActiveStore
```

You'll note the `InterfaceMetric` field also seems to indicate my packet should be sent through the 'default' interface rather than through the loopback interface.

Forcing the socket to send the packet through a different interface via `s.setsockopt(socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF, ...)` works, but I shouldn't need to do that.

You'll note that there are two Ethernet interfaces corresponding to two network cards on my motherboard. When I connected the cable to *Ethernet* instead of *Ethernet 3*, the code above started behaving as I expected and the packet was sent through that interface rather than through the loopback interface.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

On my Win10 PC there is a rule in the firewall: UDP port 5353 (mDNS) is allowed to be used by `svchost.exe` only. This basically means only some Windows services can use mDNS. You may want to check your own firewall and modify that rule - if you have it.

Comment: Disabling the firewall did not help.
It is not a firewall issue, because the packet is indeed sent - it's just sent through the loopback interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using C++ rather than python, but this helped:

```cpp
flag = 0;
setsockopt(this->socket, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, (char*) & flag,sizeof(flag))
```

Disableing **`IP_MULTICAST_LOOP`** helped!